# How to Find Inverse Laplace Transform of $ F(s)=\frac{1}{\pi} \cot^{-1}(\frac{10s}{\pi}) $

Tags: laplace-transform

$$ F(s)=\frac{\cot^{-1}(\frac{10s}{\pi})}{\pi} $$  $$ f(t) = ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know : $$ cot^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-tan^{-1}(x) $$
So :  $$ F(s)=\frac{cot^{-1}(\frac{10s}{\pi})}{\pi}= \frac{1}{\pi}(\frac{\pi}{2}-tan^{-1}(\frac{10s}{\pi})) $$
Also we know :  $$ \mathcal{L} [ -t f(t) ] = \frac{d}{ds}F(s) $$
So : $$ \frac{d}{ds}F(s)= \frac{-1}{\pi} [\frac{\frac{10}{\pi}}{(\frac{10}{\pi})^2s^2+1}]
=\frac{(\frac{1}{\pi})(\frac{-\pi}{10})}{s^2+(\frac{\pi}{10})^2} $$
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} [\frac{d}{ds}F(s)] = -t f(t)$$
$$ t f(t) = \frac{1}{\pi}sin(\frac{\pi}{10}t) $$ 
$$ f(t)=\frac{sin(\frac{\pi t}{10})}{\pi t} $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$-\pi tf(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{ds}\cot^{-1}(10s/\pi)\right)$$

Comment: $\quad + 1 \quad \ddot\smile\quad$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Recall what operation in the $t$ space corresponds to the differentiation of $F(s)$. Now find the inverse Laplace transform of $F'(s)$ and apply that operation to the result.